# Hibernate.initialize() and second-level cache

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Does anybody know if Hibernate's `static initialize()` method, which populates a proxy object, will attempt to hit the second-level cache before going to the database?  My code seems to be behaving that way, and I can't seem to find anything in the documentation about this.  The Java doc is (as usual) sparse.

Thanks!

Comment: Which initialize() method are you referring to?  Which class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does. As long as second level caching is activated and that your entity is declared cacheable, then cache takes precedence when there is no explicite querying. You can follow the cache query/hit/miss by [configuring the org.hibernate.cache logger](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging).

Comment: That's a dead link. Can you please edit it to the current reference on this. I can't find it.